# Force required to produce a specific motion on a particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics

This exercise comes from the Exercises for the Feynman Lectures, Chapter 15.

The full question:

> 15-6 A particle of rest mass $m_0$ is caused to move along a line such that
>   its position is:
>
> $$x = \sqrt{b^2+c^2t^2} - b$$
>
> What force must be applied to produce this motion?

I am assuming b is an arbitrary constant. With this in mind, I figured that I may be able to calculate the force by first finding out the acceleration of the particle.

Then we have
 $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{c^2b^2}{(b^2+c^2t^2)^{3/2}}$$

Then we have $F=ma$. However, the mass is $\gamma m_0$, where I took found $\gamma$ by substituting $v = dx/dt$. This resulted in a complex expression that did not simplify nicely.

The answer, according to the book, is

> $F = m_0 c^2 /b$

Perhaps substituting $v= dx/dt$ to find $\gamma$ isn't valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Newton's Second Law of motion in its *classical* version. 
Try to express this law in its more fundamental form where it is defined as the rate of change of total linear momentum of a system. Knowing this and the fact that total linear momentum of a system must also be represented in its relativistic form (which I assume you are aware of,) you can calculate the relativistic force.

Comment: so, $F= \frac{d}{dt} (\gamma m_0 v)$?

Comment: Many thanks, the answer popped out very soon after using that!